# Difficulty mapping normal key strokes into .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vimspector

I am trying to create a shortcut key that does the following steps in normal mode:

1. Go to stack trace window
2. Go to second line from top in this window
3. Press Enter

In step 2, the second line from top is the location of the current execution point (instruction pointer) in my debugging session. Pressing Enter on the second line from top in this stack trace window takes me to a different window that is where my current debugging session's code window is.

I have tried the following in my .vimrc

```
nnoremap <Leader>st :call GotoWindow(g:vimspector_session_windows.stack_trace)<CR> \| :execute "normal! ggj" \| <CR>
```

This brings the cursor to the 2nd line, but the final step where Enter is pressed in normal mode to go to the code window where my current execution point is, does not work at all.

Function `GotoWindow()` is as below also in .vimrc

```
fun GotoWindow(id)
    call win_gotoid(a:id)
endfun
```

Is there a way the keypresses `gg`, `j`, `Enter` can be replicated inside the .vimrc?

Comment: @BLayer That does not work either. It gives: E114: Missing quote: "normal! ggj\

Comment: Oh, I missed that that was inside a mapping. Anyways, `feedkeys()` almost always works when you need to simulate a keypress. Read `:h feedkeys()` carefully, first, though.

Comment: I tried: `nnoremap <Leader>st :call GotoWindow(g:vimspector_session_windows.stack_trace)<CR> \| :call feedkeys("ggj\<cr>")` and this returns `error E116: invalid arguments for function feedkeys`.

Comment: `nnoremap <Leader>st :call GotoWindow(g:vimspector_session_windows.stack_trace)<CR> \| :call feedkeys("gg") \| :call feedkeys("j") \| :call feedkeys("\<CR>")` gives error : E114: Missing quote: "\
E116: Invalid arguments for function feedkeys

Comment: `call feedkeys("\n", 'n')`

Comment: That does not work either. What happens when I open up vim is that as the .vimrc is getting processed, I get a < beep > sound that indicates that enter is being pressed

Comment: I don't know man, that works for me. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Thank you for your help nonetheless. I am sure I will figure it out one day :-)

Comment: No prob. Someone here will probably figure it out. I'm just not in a place where I can dive deep right now. Wait until morning USA time...more people will be available. :) If not, I'll take a closer look myself.

Comment: Possibly: `nnoremap <Leader>st :call GotoWindow(g:vimspector_session_windows.stack_trace)<CR>:2<CR><CR>`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That doesn't work either. If the stack trace call is more than 1 level deep, this goes to the current execution points *caller* and focuses the cursor there in the stack trace window. Even here, the final <CR> that should take one from the stack trace windows to the code window does not execute.

Comment: Well you asked for the second line, so that’s what we’ve been doing. Try `nmap` though, probably the enter key is mapped in that window.